# what reason can cause g_hash_table_steal to return false?

Tags: c, glib

My program uses `g_hash_table_steal` to remove a key and its associated value from a GHashTable (libglib-2.0.so.0  RedHat 7.4). But it returns false. What reason can cause `g_hash_table_steal` to return false?

Comment: scene  means   reason

Comment: Here's the documentation: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-hash-table-steal

Comment: Thanks , but it's too simple.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

A boolean can either be true or false. [The documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-hash-table-steal) for `g_hash_table_steal()` says that it returns “true if the key was found and removed from the `GHashTable`”. So therefore it must return false if the key was not found in the `GHashTable` (so could not be removed).

Comment: What do you mean? I’m not sure how I could be clearer. `g_hash_table_steal()` returns false if the key was not found in the `GHashTable`.